# Exporting GridView To Excel Requires GridView To Be Placed In a Form Tag

Tags: asp.net, gridview, export-to-excel

Been trying to export the content of the gridview, which is placed in a ContentPlaceHolder, to Excel.
Obviously no form tag is included in the .aspx page. It's in the master page.

This line `gvRapor.RenderControl(hwr);` 
gives the error:

```
Control 'cphIcerik_gvRapor' of type 'GridView' must be placed inside a form tag with runat=server.
```

the code:

```
StringWriter swr = new StringWriter();
HtmlTextWriter hwr = new HtmlTextWriter(swr);

for (int j = 0; j < gvRapor.Rows.Count; j++)
{
     GridViewRow row = gvRapor.Rows[j];
     gvRapor.RenderControl(hwr);
     Context.Response.Write(swr.ToString());
     Context.Response.Flush();
     Context.Response.End();
}
```

Tried almost all possible values for Response.ContentType, but the same!

Answer (score 1):

I think you are calling `gvRapor.RenderControl(hwr);` and i guess you would not have overloaded the `VerifyRenderingInServerForm`
Try by adding the following code in your file

```
public override void VerifyRenderingInServerForm(Control control)
{
    /* HtmlForm control is rendered at run time. */
}
```

Have a look at this [VerifyRenderingInServerForm](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.page.verifyrenderinginserverform.aspx)

I hope this helps!